# Counting total number of letters in a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, counting

a = "All men are created equal under the power of the constitution, Thomas Jefferson"

i know a.count('A') will return how many "A"s there are. But I want to count how many A's, e's, c's and T's there are and adding them together. Help much appreciated.

Im using Python3

Comment: Do you need a count of each letter separately or just the total?

Answer (score 5):

Look into `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import string
>>> c = Counter(l for l in a if l in string.ascii_letters)
>>> c
Counter({'e': 11, 't': 6, 'o': 6, 'r': 5, 'n': 5, 'a': 4, 'l': 3, 'f': 3,
         's': 3, 'u': 3, 'h': 3, 'i': 2, 'd': 2, 'c': 2, 'm': 2, 'A': 1,
         'p': 1, 'w': 1, 'T': 1, 'J': 1, 'q': 1})
>>> sum(c.values())
66
>>> c = Counter(l for l in a if l in 'AecT')
>>> c
Counter({'e': 11, 'c': 2, 'A': 1, 'T': 1})
>>> sum(c.values())
15
```

Comment: You may get a small improvement by storing `string.ascii_letters` in a set

Comment: `sum(c[x] for x in ('A', 'e', 'c', 'T'))` since OP wanted "to count how many A's, e's, c's and T's there are and adding them together"

Comment: @JohnLaRooy True, but the sample size is too small - 20 µs for bare 150 µs for set.

Comment: @mfcovington see second `Counter()`

Comment: Ya, I was commenting on an older version it seems. Also, might want to change `c` somewhere. Not simple to read `c = Counter(c for c in a if c ...` since `c` represents both a Counter and a letter.

Comment: Thanks, replaced with `l` for letter - though pep8 recommends against using `l` :)

Answer (score 2):

Python has a great module for this. Use Counter from collections

```
from collections import Counter
a = "All men are created equal under the power of the constitution, Thomas Jefferson"
counter = Counter(a)

print(counter)
```

It will output a dictionary of all letters as keys and the values will be the occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex expressions to find the total number of letters easily

```
import re
p = re.compile("\w")
a = "All men are created equal under the power of the constitution, Thomas Jefferson"
numberOfLetters = len(p.findall(a))
```

Will return 66.

If you just want A,e,c, and T you should use this regex instead:

```
p = re.compile("[A|e|c|T]")
```

Will return 15.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried with an another approach

```
map(lambda x: [x, a.count(x)], 'AecT')
```

'a' is the input string. 'AecT' can replace with required letters as per the need.

Comment: Repeating `'a'` was a little confusing and counting `a` would include punctation, so changed to OP's request (alternatively can use `string.ascii_letters` for just letters)